# Marklogic - wildcarded search not working for slash (/)

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using the below xquery for partial  search ,The does not work when the string coming with slash (/) .

The Query should return the URI based on Search.

Xquery:

```
cts:search(fn:collection($collectionName),

    cts:and-query((

    cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("element"),xs:QName("type"),'per'),

    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("attri"),'*Olliffe Matthew 17/2/3*',("wildcarded","whitespace-sensitive","case-insensitive"))

)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in MarkLogic 9.0-1.1 console, for me variable $collectionName is "coll1".

```
cts:search(fn:collection("coll1"),
                                 cts:and-query((

                                 cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("element"),xs:QName("type"),'per'),

                                cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("attri"),'*Olliffe Matthew 17/2/3*',("wildcarded","whitespace-sensitive","case-insensitive"))

                        )))
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for your updating. But I am using 6.0-6.1 .